# Grep not parsing the whole file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to use grep to pick lines not containing "WAT" in a file containing 425409 lines with a file size of 26.8 MB, UTF8 encoding.

The file looks like this

```
>ATOM      1 N    ALA     1       9.979 -15.619  28.204  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM      2 H1   ALA     1       9.594 -15.053  28.938  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM      3 H2   ALA     1       9.558 -15.358  27.323  1.00  0.00    
>ATOM     12 O    ALA     1       7.428 -16.246  28.335  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     13 N    HID     2       7.563 -18.429  28.562  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     14 H    HID     2       6.557 -18.369  28.638  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     15 CA   HID     2       8.082 -19.800  28.535  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     24 HE1  HID     2       8.603 -23.670  33.041  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     25 NE2  HID     2       8.012 -23.749  30.962  1.00  0.00    
>ATOM     29 O    HID     2       5.854 -20.687  28.537  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     30 N    GLN     3       7.209 -21.407  26.887  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     31 H    GLN     3       8.168 -21.419  26.566  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM     32 CA   GLN     3       6.271 -22.274  26.157  1.00  0.00  

**16443 lines**  

>ATOM  16425 C116 PA   1089     -34.635   6.968  -0.185  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16426 H16R PA   1089     -35.669   7.267  -0.368  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16427 H16S PA   1089     -34.579   5.878  -0.218  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16428 H16T PA   1089     -34.016   7.366  -0.990  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16429 C115 PA   1089     -34.144   7.493   1.177  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16430 H15R PA   1089     -33.101   7.198   1.305  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16431 H15S PA   1089     -34.179   8.585   1.197  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16432 C114 PA   1089     -34.971   6.910   2.342  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  16433 H14R PA   1089     -35.147   5.847   2.166  1.00  0.00  

**132284 lines**

>ATOM  60981 O    WAT  7952     -46.056  -5.515 -56.245  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60982 H1   WAT  7952     -45.185  -5.238 -56.602  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60983 H2   WAT  7952     -46.081  -6.445 -56.561  1.00  0.00  
>TER     
>ATOM  60984 O    WAT  7953     -51.005  -3.205 -46.712  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60985 H1   WAT  7953     -51.172  -3.159 -47.682  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60986 H2   WAT  7953     -51.051  -4.177 -46.579  1.00  0.00  
>TER     
>ATOM  60987 O    WAT  7954     -49.804  -0.759 -49.284  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60988 H1   WAT  7954     -48.962  -0.677 -49.785  1.00  0.00  
>ATOM  60989 H2   WAT  7954     -49.868   0.138 -48.903  1.00  0.00

**many lines until the end** 

>TER
>END
```

I have used `grep -v 'WAT' file.txt` but it only returned me the first 16179 lines not containing "WAT" and I can see that there are more lines not containing "WAT". For instance, the following line (and many others) does not appear in the output:

```
> ATOM  16425 C116 PA   1089     -34.635   6.968  -0.185  1.00  0.00
```

In order to try to figure out what was happening I've tried `grep ' ' file.txt`. This command should return every line in the file, but it only returned he first 16179 lines too.
I've also tried to use `tail -408977 file.txt | grep ' '` and it returned me all lines recalled by tail. Then I've tried `tail -408978 file.txt | grep ' '` and the output was totally empty, zero lines.
I am working on a "normal" 64 bit system, Kubuntu.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try I get

```
$: grep WAT file.txt
Binary file file.txt matches
```

grep is assuming it's a binary file. add `-a`

> -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text

```
$: grep -a WAT file.txt|head -3
ATOM  29305 O    WAT  4060     -75.787 -79.125  25.925  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM  29306 H1   WAT  4060     -76.191 -78.230  25.936  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM  29307 H2   WAT  4060     -76.556 -79.670  25.684  1.00  0.00           H
```

> Your file has 2 NULLs each at the end of lines 16426, 16428, 16430, and 16432.

```
$: tr "\0" @ <file.txt|grep -n @
16426:ATOM  16421 KA   CAL  1085     -20.614 -22.960  18.641  1.00  0.00          @@
16428:ATOM  16422 KA   CAL  1086      20.249  21.546  19.443  1.00  0.00          @@
16430:ATOM  16423 KA   CAL  1087      22.695 -19.700  19.624  1.00  0.00          @@
16432:ATOM  16424 KA   CAL  1088     -22.147  19.317  17.966  1.00  0.00          @@
```

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHAKSFGSBLKJVBAS;DV

Comment: LOL! Glad I could help.
What's in the file that's making it do that, I wonder?

Comment: Sorry, gone crazy! Thanks a lot. I have 11 of reputation, so my vote is not displayed, but already casted.

Comment: I have NO IDEA of what is making it do that... A total mistery for me. A black box.

Comment: Appended the answer with a way to see them.

Comment: The nulls are on 4 lines: 16426, 16428, 16430, 16432. Using: `sed -i 's/\x0/!!!/g' min14.pdb` Anyway that doesn't answer why grep behaves different and works with `grep AT` or `grep ATOM` but not `grep WAT` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary

Comment: Ok, the behaviour of grep is stopping when the first NUL is found, so it will match any string before the first NUL. In this case AT and ATOM appear before line 16426 (first NUL) but the first match for 'WAT' only appears in line 132285.